# Kill (like ctrl+c) exec (child process) on nodejs

Tags: javascript, node.js, exec, child-process

I have the following code in index.js:

```
var child = exec(
    'node app.js --board=' + data.data.board + ' --link=' + data.data.link,
    function (error, stdout, stderr) {
        if (error) console.log('exec error: ' + error)
        if (stderr) console.log('stderr: ' + stderr)
    }
)
.stdout.on('data', function(log_data) {
    console.log(log_data)
    socket.emit('listener', { ty: 'user_p_logs', num: data.num, log: log_data })
    fn(true)
})
```

This is the code for the `run app.js`, but I cannot stop this child process on `index.js`

I tried the following in `index.js`:

```
child.kill()
child.kill('SIGINT')
process.exit() // This stopped index.js, instead of its child.
```

update: any answers ?

Comment: You need to assign the process to `child` so you can kill it.

Comment: How can i do this ?

Answer (score 0):

What you're assigning to `child` is the return value of `.stdout.on`, which is the `stdout` event emitter, not the `child` process. You need it to be the child process. Don't overdo the chaining. :-)

```
var child = exec(
    'node app.js --board=' + data.data.board + ' --link=' + data.data.link,
    function (error, stdout, stderr) {
        if (error) console.log('exec error: ' + error)
        if (stderr) console.log('stderr: ' + stderr)
    }
);
child.stdout.on('data', function(log_data) {
    console.log(log_data)
    socket.emit('listener', { ty: 'user_p_logs', num: data.num, log: log_data })
    fn(true)
});
```

Then, `child.kill` should work.

Comment: I got this error 'Cannot read property 'kill' of undefined' when i tried your answer.

Comment: @User9123 - Then the `exec` you're using isn't [`child_process.exec`](https://nodejs.org/api/child_process.html#child_process_child_process_exec_command_options_callback), which clearly documents it returns a [`ChildProcess` object](https://nodejs.org/api/child_process.html#child_process_class_childprocess), which has a [`kill`](https://nodejs.org/api/child_process.html#child_process_subprocess_kill_signal) method.

Comment: I'm using child_process like this "const exec = require('child_process').exec"